# Cant mass-assign protected attributes issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mass-assignment

I know all the security reasons behind why mass-assigning is bad, what I cant figure out is why my app is trying to do a mass assign.

I am just trying to **create a new record** of my Section model and I am getting the "Can't mass-assign protected attributes" error.  Below are the possible involved models.  Can someone please explain to me how this is a mass-assigning?  I am new to rails, so I could be missing something very simple.

```
class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :type, :foreign_key => 'type_id', :class_name => 'SectionType'
  attr_accessor :order
end

class SectionType < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :template
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sections
  attr_accessible :description, :name, :short, :status, :subtitle, :version

  def to_param
    return name.gsub(/\s+/, '%20')
  end
end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am new to rails and know this is probably a simple problem, but I have been trying to find an answer and can not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're attempting to create a new `Section` object and that's failing, that'd be because you don't have any attributes listed as accessible inside that model. You will need to do that, using a similar call to `attr_accessible` as the one you have in your `Project` model already.

Comment: So just change arre_accessor to attr_accessible?  or also add :project and :type to it?

Comment: So the solution for me was I needed to use `attr_accessible :order, :project_id, :type_id`  not just `attr_accessible :order, :project, :type`